# Best wood to mill for building a deck

Tags: wood, deck, outdoor

I want to build a large deck in the south (TN specifically). I have a friend with a large forested property and a mill who will allow me access to affordable wood, should I mill it myself.

I understand there is a long drying process involved, but my question is which type of wood should I look to mill for the project. I know he has black walnut, pine, and birch for sure. What wood should I be using for this project that will hold up in my local climate?

Comment: Cedar, cypress, redwood are examples of woods that you may target for a deck application. The ones you mentioned are too valuable to be used in this way.

Comment: Of the species you describe, I'd go with pine but it's not going to hold up like pressure treated lumber, redwood, etc.  Walnut is far to valuable to use for a deck - if you want to cut the walnut, sell it and use the proceeds to by pressure treated lumber for the deck.

Comment: Any black locust on the property?

Comment: Not that I am aware of